# Population stability index of XGBoost model

Tags: r, xgboost, psi

Can a Population stability index (PSI) be calculated for the XGBoost splits?

When I make a logistic regression with grouped variables, I can make PSI with the groups and see if the population in the groups are shifted to other groups.

Can this be done with the XGBoost splits?
If it can't, what is the best option to track this metric?
A mean, mode for the raw variables?

Comment: This is not a coding question and should be asked on Cross Validated. Good luck!